# How to boxplot different columns from a dataframe (y axis) vs groupby a range of hours (x axis) using plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, boxplot

Good morning,

I'm trying to boxplot the 'columns' from 1 to 6 vs the 'ElapsedTime(hours)' column with the use of plotly library.

Here is my dataframe :

```
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| Date       | Time     | Column1  | Column2 | Column3  | Column4  | Column5 | Column6  | ElapsedTime(hours) |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 29/07/2021 | 06:48:37 | 0,011535 | 8,4021  | 0,00027  | 0,027806 | 8,431   | 0,000362 | 0                  |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 29/07/2021 | 06:59:37 | 0,013458 | 8,4421  | 0,000314 | 0,032214 | 8,4738  | 0,000416 | 0,183333333        |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 29/07/2021 | 07:14:37 | 0,017793 | 8,4993  | 0,000384 | 0,038288 | 8,5372  | 0,000486 | 0,433333333        |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 30/07/2021 | 08:12:50 | 0,018808 | 8,545   | 0,000414 | 0,042341 | 8,5891  | 0,000539 | 24,9702778         |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 30/07/2021 | 08:42:50 | 0,025931 | 8,3627  | 0,000534 | 0,032379 | 8,3556  | 0,000557 | 25,9036111         |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 30/07/2021 | 08:57:50 | 0,025164 | 8,5518  | 0,000505 | 0,041134 | 8,6516  | 0,000254 | 26,1536111         |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 31/07/2021 | 05:45:28 | 0,026561 | 8,6266  | 0,000533 | 0,050387 | 8,6718  | 0,00065  | 46,9475            |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 31/07/2021 | 05:55:28 | 0,027744 | 8,6455  | 0,000543 | 0,051511 | 8,6916  | 0,000664 | 47,11416667        |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 31/07/2021 | 06:05:28 | 0,028854 | 8,485   | 0,000342 | 0,05693  | 8,6934  | 0,000695 | 47,28083333        |
+------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

for now, i just know how to boxplot each column vs nothing using these lines of **code** :

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category= UserWarning)

da = pd.DataFrame()
da['Date'] = ["29/07/2021", "29/07/2021", "29/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "31/07/2021", "31/07/2021", "31/07/2021"]
da['Time'] = ["06:48:37", "06:59:37", "07:14:37", "08:12:50", "08:42:50", "08:57:50", "05:45:28", "05:55:28", "06:05:28"]
da["Column1"] = [0.011534891, 0.013458399,  0.017792937, 0.018807581, 0.025931434, 0.025163517, 0.026561283, 0.027743659, 0.028854]
da["Column2"] = [8.4021, 8.4421, 8.4993, 8.545, 8.3627, 8.5518, 8.6266, 8.6455, 8.485]
da["Column3"] = [0.000270475, 0.000313769,  0.000383506,  0.000414331,  0.000533619,  0.000505081,  0.000533131,  0.000543031,  0.000342]
da["Column4"] = [0.027806399, 0.032213984,  0.038287754,  0.042340721,  0.032378571,  0.041134106,  0.050387029,  0.051511238,  0.05693]
da["Column5"] = [8.431,   8.4738,   8.5372,   8.5891,   8.3556,   8.6516,   8.6718,   8.6916,   8.6934]
da["Column6"] = [0.000362081, 0.000416463,  0.000486275,  0.000539244,  0.000556613,  0.000253831,  0.00064975,   0.000664063,  0.000695]
da["ElapsedTime(hours)"] = [0,    0.183333333,  0.433333333,  24.9702778,   25.9036111,   26.1536111,   46.9475,  47.11416667,  47.28083333]
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(y=da['Column1'], name='Column1'))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(y=da['Column2'], name='Column2'))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(y=da['Column3'], name='Column3'))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(y=da['Column4'], name='Column4'))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(y=da['Column5'], name='Column5'))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(y=da['Column6'], name='Column6'))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=1.24,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.15
))
from plotly import offline
offline.plot(fig)
```

Output :
[image]

I can choose to show one column :
[image]

**What i want (if possible)** : Plot my columns from 1 to 6 vs a range of ElapsedTime(hours). For exemple i choose to have a range of 10 hours, so the boxplots will be taking in consideration that range and plot all the values of that range into one box.

**PS** : if i add x=da['ElapsedTime(hours)'] inside the go.Box(), i will be ploting each value of columns 1 to 6 versus one value from the ElapsedTime column and i don't want that, I want a box in a range of an ElapsedTime.

**Extra** : If possible, i want the columns from 1 to 6 to be in a dropdown button so that i can click and choose which column i wanna see in the range of the ElapsedTime i choosed.

Thank you for your time, and have a great day !

**EDIT :**#################################################

I tried these lines. The problem is that i have an error saying dataframe doesn't have a name argument (name=data.name) and if i get rid of that, let's say i don't use name=data.name, i will get a plot that is not Box. Do you have any idea on how to overcome this problem ?

```
da["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(da.Date + " " + da.Time)
columns = [c for c in da.columns if c.startswith("Column")]
da.set_index("DateTime")[columns].resample("1D")

fig = go.Figure()
for start_datetime, data in da.set_index("DateTime")[columns].resample("1D"):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Box(x=data.index, y=data.values, name=data.name))
    fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
        yanchor="top",
        y=1.24,
        xanchor="left",
        x=0.15
    ))
fig.update_layout(boxmode='group')
from plotly import offline
offline.plot(fig)
```

Comment: if you have the code that generates that example of the dataframe given, that would be most useful...

Comment: @D.L I just used an excel file. I don't know how to upload it here, can you tell me please ?

Comment: okay.  you could make a *small sample dataframe*. basically, users need to be able to reproduce the problem to solve it:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  .

Comment: @D.L I updated my code in that way. thx !

Comment: You have numeric data like 0.011534891 but enclose it in quotes.  It will then be interpreted as string.  Please use `.` as decimal separator and do not quote floats.

Comment: @MichaelKopp Oh my bad sorry, i'll check your suggestion for aggregation and try to manage something with it. Thank you !

Comment: In response to your edit of the question, I think the issue is that the loop process data does not have a name, so it is an error. But even if the error is resolved, it will not be the graph you are looking for. If I convert the data in wide format to vertical format and change to a loop process for each day, it draws a boxplot for each group of days, but the data ranges for each are so far apart that I cannot make a boxplot decision. Therefore, setting the graph to a much larger height does not improve the situation, so a countermeasure is needed.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you for your response. For the code you did, he is not ploting in the X-axis the dates, he is ploting the variations on the Y-axis versus the column name and you have the option to choose for which day you wanna see the boxplot for each column and it is exactly what i got before my edited question. Could you manage to have something which has the columns values on the Y-axis versus each date on the X-axis and the buttons (which is the option "name" in go.Box() ) will have the columns name so you will have 6 buttons for Column1 to Column6.

Comment: Is the x-axis the date of what you were looking for? I didn't understand so I will disable the Colab link. I have not verified this, but why not just change the x-axis to a date?

Comment: @r-beginners To make it simple and clear, you see my first code before the edit ? I ploted each box manually for each column but i didn't mention the X-axis because it will plot "lines" or lined box for each timestamp, so, i want to do a loop over 1Day for example you will have all the columns values for that day ploted on the Y-axis versus date on the X-axis and the 'name' argument will be the name of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions.

1. Merge the Date and Time columns into a DateTime column:

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   da = pd.DataFrame()
   da['Date'] = ["29/07/2021", "29/07/2021", "29/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "30/07/2021", "31/07/2021", "31/07/2021", "31/07/2021"]
   da['Time'] = ["06:48:37", "06:59:37", "07:14:37", "08:12:50", "08:42:50", "08:57:50", "05:45:28", "05:55:28", "06:05:28"]
   da["Column1"] = [0.011534891, 0.013458399,  0.017792937, 0.018807581, 0.025931434, 0.025163517, 0.026561283, 0.027743659, 0.028854]
   da["Column2"] = [8.4021, 8.4421, 8.4993, 8.545, 8.3627, 8.5518, 8.6266, 8.6455, 8.485]
   da["Column3"] = [0.000270475, 0.000313769,  0.000383506,  0.000414331,  0.000533619,  0.000505081,  0.000533131,  0.000543031,  0.000342]
   da["Column4"] = [0.027806399, 0.032213984,  0.038287754,  0.042340721,  0.032378571,  0.041134106,  0.050387029,  0.051511238,  0.05693]
   da["Column5"] = [8.431,   8.4738,   8.5372,   8.5891,   8.3556,   8.6516,   8.6718,   8.6916,   8.6934]
   da["Column6"] = [0.000362081, 0.000416463,  0.000486275,  0.000539244,  0.000556613,  0.000253831,  0.00064975,   0.000664063,  0.000695]
   da["ElapsedTime(hours)"] = [0,    0.183333333,  0.433333333,  24.9702778,   25.9036111,   26.1536111,   46.9475,  47.11416667,  47.28083333]

   da["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + " " + df.Time)

   df = da  # df is more natural for me ;)
   ```

   I use the following to mark the interesting columns:

   ```
   columns = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("Column")]
   ```
2. Use the [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) method, to aggregate data over some time range.

   For example to aggregate over one day, use

   ```
   df.set_index("DateTime")[columns].resample("1D")
   ```

   The result is an object, that you can either run some aggregations on, e.g. compute the mean for each such sample:

   ```
   df.set_index("DateTime")[columns].resample("1D").mean()
   ```

   If you want to leverage plotly's functionality to create the boxplot, I would use a loop though:

   ```
   for start_datetime, data in df.set_index("DateTime")[columns].resample("1D"):
       print(start_datetime)
       print(data)
       print()
   ```

   Instead of the `print` functions, use the plotly commands to create a box in the boxplot.

Comment: Instead of dropdowns, I usually use the built-in functionality of plotly to click on an item in the legend to show/hide the corresponding values in the graph.  This allows me to show either only one interesting set of values or add more for a comparison.

Comment: That's what i'm using for the code i did, but i just wanted that dropdown as a "fancy" way to plot x)

Comment: I tried what you suggested with the loop, but it's not ploting what i want